# How to hide SVG tag from IE8

Tags: html, css, svg

I have HTML page where I render SVG and all works fine in modern browsers and IE9+. IE8 however doesn't display svg and all I see is empty box. I'm trying to make IE8 and older browsers not to render it at all but all attempts at usual `display: none;`, `width: 0` etc failed. I tried to hide it via JS call but nothing seems to work. If I change width/height directly in HTML it seems to work though. My SVG part is below, if anyone could give me an idea how to get IE not to display this SVG tag that would be great.

```
<div class="slide panel">

<svg width="1000" height="500">
    <mask  width="1000" height="500"  maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="m1">

        <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="200" fill="white" />

    </mask>
    <image preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"  mask="url(#m1)" xlink:href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/banner1.jpg" width="1000" height="500" class="target"/>
</svg>

<!-- the rest of HTML code -->
```

EDIT: this is wordpress site so an option would be detecting what browser made request in php and returning different HTML for IE8 only. Is this reliable solution though? How usually is it done?

EDIT2: Found solution.. I ended up wrapping svg in another div and setting it to `display: none;` for IE8 only, changing size via JS, css etc didnt work at all on SVG tag itself.. God, I hate IE :/

Comment: For IE8-, `svg` tag seems to be just an unknown tag, like HTML5's `article`, `nav` etc. I suppose that the same trick with `document.createElement('svg');` will enable basic styling of it with CSS, like it does for these tags.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to wrap your SVGs into another element. It's sufficient to add proper namespace declarations and target those, like:

```
[xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"] {
  display: none;
}
```

You could also use modernizr, a custom test or a simple html tag switch with conditional comments to add the classes inlinesvg and no-inlinesvg (or something similar), respectively, to the HTML tag:

```
.no-inlinesvg [xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would not hide SVG, instead use this little hack that gets the job done.

```
<img src="image.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='image.png'">
```

[Additional Info](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer here, but in my testing, Josh C's solution won't work, presumably because since IE8 doesn't know what an `<svg>` is, it isn't able to apply styles to it.

What worked in my case was to wrap the `<svg>` in a `<div id="svgWrapper">`. Then a modification of Josh's solution works quite nicely:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <style type="text/css">
    #svgWrapper { display: none; }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

In my particular case, I was already adding an outer wrapper class in the case of IE, so all I needed was a new style targeting `.ie8 #svgWrapper` and it seemed to test well.

EDIT: I need to learn to read better. Clearly the OP reached the same conclusion and answer was totally unnecessary.