# Hide inline <SVG> in IE8

Tags: html, css, svg, internet-explorer-8

I have 2 `<svg>`'s on a page which break the layout in IE8 (as it's not supported) so I need to hide both of them, which I thought would be a matter of adding `display: none;` to each of the ID's but apparently not! I'm assuming this is because IE8 has no idea what an `<svg>` is or what to do with it?

My mark-up for both `<svg>` is the following:

```
    <svg id="billboard-svg" version="1.1" viewBox="-679.6 69.3 1646.3 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax slice" width="100%" height="400">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="svgbg" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="500" height="300">
                <image xlink:href="img/interface/bg-lightpaperfibers.png" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="300" />
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <path fill="url(#svgbg)" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M-696.2,247.3c336.3,90.5,609.6,109.9,796.2,110.5c64.1,0.2,105.5,0.4,165.2-4.1c244.8-18.5,365.5-82.4,702.3-132.2c15.9-2.4,28.7-4.1,36.1-5.2L987.2,638l-1689.8,2.7L-696.2,247.3z" />
    </svg>
```

And:

```
    <svg id="footer-svg" width="100%" height="160" viewBox="0 0 1200 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" baseProfile="full">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="svgbg" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="500" height="300">
                <image xlink:href="img/interface/bg-lightpaperfibers.png" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="300" />
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <path id="wave" fill="url(#svgbg)" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"  d="M 0,40 q 300,60 600,0 T 1210,20 l 0,-580 -1210,0" />
    </svg>
```

So I tried `#billboard-svg, #footer-svg {display: none;}` which did absolutely nothing. I then read you could target the 'xmlns', so I tried that with something like:

```
[xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Which seemed to get rid of the big 'missing image' that was taking up a lot of space but the layout was still broken, almost like it had removed part of the svg mark-up but not all of it?

Would really appreciate some help on this if anyone can!

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide SVG tag from IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565585/how-to-hide-svg-tag-from-ie8)

Comment: Thanks, I tried some of the stuff mentioned on that topic but couldn't get it to work. Wasn't sure if it was maybe because of the `<defs>` , `<pattern>`, `<image>` or <`path`> tags I have in my mark-up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have IE8 handy to test, but have you tried wrapping the `<svg>` with IE conditionals?

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <svg>
    ...etc...
  </svg>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I think the If statement will work great, though I feel a bit dirty surrounding my mark-up in it just for IE8 ...but I guess there mightn't be another way! I just need to get over my pride haha!

Answer (score 0):

The thing that finally fixed this issue for me was to remove the xml namespace attribute - `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` - which I tried thanks to this post: http://stuntbox.com/blog/2013/06/bulletproof-inline-svg/

Looks like only one `<svg>` in your posted code contains the xmlns attribute, but you could try adjusting the self-closing `<path>` elements to have a separate closing tag, as recommended in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Add an IE conditional comment to the html element.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9 ]><html lang="en" class="old-ie"><![endif]-->
<html lang="en">
```

And then target the class in CSS.

```
.old-ie #billboard-svg {
   display: none;
}
```